# javascript module pattern returning return?

Tags: javascript

Studying Module pattern in javascript and see below..
Question.. why do you need return inside of return? what purpose does that serve?

```
   var ex = function(){
        return {
            get: function(name){
                console.log("helloe " + name);
                return {
                    hostname: 'node1 '
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are returning an object literal.

```
var ex = function(){
    return {
```

Here you are declaring a function `get` inside that object literal.

```
get: function(name){
```

Here, you are returning an object literal each time the `get` function is called.

```
  return {
     hostname: 'node1 '
  }
```

Comment: understand this and appreciate it but I would love to see practical reason why this is call this way? I would think it's just simple to return {get: { hostname: 'node1'} } .  what is the difference between that and return { get: function(name)}; return { hostname: 'node1'}} ??

Comment: Then I need to know what module system you are talking about, It does seam like an unnecessary complexity, do you have the links you are reading?

Comment: I will accept your answer(it's detailed and broken into steps). thank you. It was from some video tutorial. thank you